# Is it possible to set the context of scroll event to `document.body` instead of `window`?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, dom-events

### Backdrop

While I was reading [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) page, I noticed that the left and right sidebars have their scrollbars contained within themselves. But the content area block has its scrollbar in the global context.

[image: demonstration]

When I inspected the DOM tree, I saw that the `body` and `html` tags doesn't have height property defined on them. So essentially, their were no elements with fixed height (scrollable container) between the content area and the topmost window object.
[An example of scrollable container](https://live-samples.mdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop/_sample_.scrolling_an_element.html)

### Problem

So this makes `window` the overflow container for the content area.
Further confirming this, I added `scroll` event listeners to both `window` and `document.body` and it turns out that only `window` event is fired

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",(e)=>console.log("window scrolling")) 

document.body.addEventListener("scroll",(e)=>console.log("bodyy scrolling"))
```

But I want the context for scroll should not be `window` but `document.body`. And that **should fire scroll event from body tag and not window.**

### What I did

I then added `height` property to the `body` tag.

```
height: 100vh
```

and then added scroll event listener to it again. But It didn't fired, and I am not able to understand why it didn't?

Adding a `height` property to a parent which has a value  less than its children should make it scrollable right?

I might be missing something fundamental but don't know what?
Please help, Thanks!

ref-

- [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)
- [scrollTop property of an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)
- [Scroll
  container definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scroll_container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to set the `overflow` property on the `<body>`, and on the `<html>` element to something other than `visible` because of [Overflow Viewport Propagation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-propagation).

For a scrollbar to appear, `<body>`'s height must additionally be less than the content's it contains:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => console.log("window scrolled"));
document.body.addEventListener("scroll", () => console.log("body scrolled"));
```

```css
html {overflow-y: hidden}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100dvh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
main {
  height: 200%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main></main>
</body>
```

Comment: I would prefer `dvh`, so some wierd mobile behaviours doesnt appear

Comment: So essentially, scroll event won't be propagated upward, if the element there is not scrollable. Great, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the important, but not quite obvious, propagation detail. Never miss `html` style and set `body: 100vh` / `dvh` but **not** `100%`;